# Android 14 / SDK34 - Media Projection Service keeps asking for user permission

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm working on an Android App which records the user's screen every 5 seconds and generates an mp4 video file. When using the SDK 33 or lower, the service behaved as expected by asking permissions permission only once as long as the same capture intent granted after getting the activity result is used on each recording cycle.

Now, I'm currently migrating to SDK 34, but now the App requests media projection permissions before each recording cycle (even when using the same capture intent for all cycles). I'm aware of the new Behavior changes for Apps targeting Android 14 or higher, but still I'm trying to find a way around it.

Anyone having similar issues?
Any ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// RUN SERVICE AND START RECORDING
  public void runService() {

    if (!permissionGranted) {
      MediaProjectionManager manager = (MediaProjectionManager) mainActivity
          .getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
      Intent intent = null;
      if (manager != null) {
        intent = manager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
        mainActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_CODE);
        permissionGranted = true;
      } else if (reactContext != null) {
        onPermissionResult(reactContext, "capture-intent-error");
      }
    } else {
      start(CAPTURE_INTENT, INIT_RESULT_CODE);
    }
  }

  // ON MEDIAPROJECTION ACTIVITY RESULT
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    INIT_RESULT_CODE = resultCode;
    CAPTURE_INTENT = intent;
    if (resultCode == -1 && reactContext != null) {
      onPermissionResult(reactContext, "granted");
    } else if (resultCode == 0 && reactContext != null) {
      onPermissionResult(reactContext, "denied");
    }
    start(intent, resultCode);
  }
```

Comment: Your service will need to be a foreground service, continuously running, to support your every-five-seconds behavior. I would hope that you would only need to call `getMediaProjection()` once and use the resulting `MediaProjection` for the lifetime of the service.